# How to analyze time tracking reports with awk?

Tags: time, awk, time-tracking

I'm tracking my time with two great tools, [todotxt](http://todotxt.com/) and [punch](http://code.google.com/p/punch-time-tracking). With these one
            can generate reports that look like this:

```
2012-11-23 (2 hours 56 minutes):
    first task (52 minutes)
    second task (2 hours 4 minutes)
2012-11-24 (2 hours 8 minutes):
    second task (2 hours 8 minutes)
```

My question: what's a convenient way for analyzing this kind of output? E.g.
how could I sum up the time that is spent doing "first task"/"second task" or find out
            my total working hours for a longer period such as "2012-11-*"?

So, I'd like to have a command such as `punch.sh report /regex-for-date-or-task-i'm-interested-in/`.

I [read](http://snippets.aktagon.com/snippets/15-Log-file-analysis-with-AWK-Calculating-the-sum-and-average) and [saw](https://github.com/tobym/pom) that this is possible with `awk`. But I don't know how to 1) sum minutes + hours and 2) provide "task names with spaces" as variables for awk.

**UPDATE:**
I'm also tagging my tasks with `+tags` to mark different projects (as in `first task +projecttag`). So it would also be great to sum the time spent on all tasks with a certain tag.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before running this script. Please uncomment the appropriate `gsub()` function. Run like:

```
awk -f script.awk file
```

Contents of `script.awk`:

```
BEGIN {
    FS="[( \t)]"
}

/^\t/ {
    line = $0

#### If your input has...

##   No tags, show hrs in each task
#    gsub(/^[\t ]*| *\(.*/,"",line)

##   Tags, show hrs in each task
#    gsub(/^[\t ]*| *\+.*/,"",line)

##   Tags, show hrs in each tag
#    gsub(/^[^+]*\+| *\(.*/,"",line)

####

    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        if ($i == "hours") h[line]+=$(i-1)
        if ($i == "minutes") m[line]+=$(i-1)
    }
}

END {
    for (i in m) {
        while (m[i] >= 60) { m[i]-=60; h[i]++ }
        print i ":", (h[i] ? h[i] : "0") " hrs", m[i], "mins"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works great -- only the indented task lines should actually start with a tab, not four spaces (I had it wrong in the example for some reason). I got a bit confused about the regex (I'm not a coder), so can you please fix this for me?

Comment: Easy. All I changed was `/^ / {` to `/^\t/ {` on the 5th line. HTH

Comment: @steve, Your script works, but the contents of the file is:`second task (2 hours 4 minutes)`; `second task (2 hours 58 minutes)` Print results -> `second task: 4 hrs 62 mins`

Comment: @Tedee12345: I think you've got a typo in your datafile. `second task (2 hours 58 minutes)` should really be `second task (2 hours 8 minutes)`

Comment: @steve, You're right. I changed the contents of the file. I wanted to check if the script converts minutes to hours -> `5 hrs 2 mins`

Comment: @mart: Thanks mate. Are you still looking to calculate the hours of each task between two dates?

Comment: @steve: This would be great, but I'm thinking now that it's not crucial. So don't worry if you're busy these days. However, it would be nice to have another additional feature -- see the updated question. Can you help?

Comment: @mart: Sure. I should be able to put something together for you

Comment: @mart: I've edited the answer (sorry for the wait, was on the phone). It won't work out of the box; you'll have to decide what you'd like to do using what input. You can do this by uncommenting the `gsub()` function you'd like to use. I've also updated the way in which the hrs/mins are calculated to make things a bit more intelligent. Please let me know what you think. Cheers.