# How to add up hours and minutes spent on a task in AWK?

Tags: logging, awk, timestamp, gawk, time-tracking

The time tracking tool [punch](http://code.google.com/p/punch-time-tracking/) generates a timelog that includes a task and timestamps as in "yyyymmddThhmmss":

```
task    started         ended
---------------------------------------
task1   20121107T114348 20121107T120921
task2   20121107T121349 20121107T121430
task2   20121107T121658 20121107T124255
task1   20121107T140935 20121107T144153
task2   20121107T163449 20121107T180431
```

How could I sum the total hours and minutes spent on every task **specified in a regex**? E.g. to add up time spent on tasks that contain `my-regex`, an `awk` or `gawk` command would be something like this:

```
awk '/my-regex/ { summing-of-corresponding-timestamps }' logfile.log
```

This is an addition to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13547138/how-to-analyze-time-tracking-reports-with-awk) -- I realized I'm in need of a more "robust", regex-based solution. But I'm not a coder, so summing minutes and hours in AWK got me really confused. Thanks for any help!

Comment: awk doesn't have any built-in support for timestamps, so you'd probably end up writing one function to determine the number of seconds between the "started" and "ended" timestamps, and another function to format elapsed seconds in the form "hh:mm". (Or search online; someone's probably already written these functions.) Usually awk is my "go to" language for this kind of thing, but for this particular job I'd think hard about picking a different language, one that has better support for timestamp arithmetic.

Comment: thanks for the comment. which language would you suggest?

Comment: If I can't do something easily with awk, I usually try python first.

Comment: GNU awk, gawk, absolutely DOES have built in support for timestamps. See the mktime(), strftime(), and systime() functions.

Comment: @EdMorton: Good point. I don't have gawk here. I get so used to what's available here that I sometimes forget there are other dialects. I'll +1 your comment for that, and leave my earlier idiocy as it is for a reminder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this with GNU awk, I haven't checked the math:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR<3{ next }
{
   start = mktime(gensub(/(....)(..)(..).(..)(..)(..)/,"\\1 \\2 \\3 \\4 \\5 \\6","",$2))
   end   = mktime(gensub(/(....)(..)(..).(..)(..)(..)/,"\\1 \\2 \\3 \\4 \\5 \\6","",$3))
   dur[$1] += end - start
}
END {
   for (task in dur)
      print task, dur[task]
}
$
$ gawk -f tst.awk file
task1 3471
task2 6980
```

The outputs in seconds, massage to suit...

EDIT: to get the total duration of all tasks that satisfy some RE would be:

```
NR<3{ next }
$1 ~ re {
   start = mktime(gensub(/(....)(..)(..).(..)(..)(..)/,"\\1 \\2 \\3 \\4 \\5 \\6","",$2))
   end   = mktime(gensub(/(....)(..)(..).(..)(..)(..)/,"\\1 \\2 \\3 \\4 \\5 \\6","",$3))
   dur += end - start
}
END {
   print dur
}

$ gawk -v re='<specify your RE>' -f tst.awk file
```

***STEVE'S EDIT:***

This answer is almost there. I've made a few small changes incorporating the information from the comments above/below. You can change the regex as required, for example:

```
awk '/task/ { a = "(....)(..)(..).(..)(..)(..)"; b = "\\1 \\2 \\3 \\4 \\5 \\6"; t += mktime(gensub(a, b, "", $NF)) - mktime(gensub(a, b, "", $(NF-1))) } END { print t }' file
```

Results:

```
10451
```

Comment: Thank you! However, this doesn't seem to work with tasks containing multiple words. Also, my main goal is to be able to **filter the log file according to a regular expression that I give as an agrument to the gawk script**. After this, the script would calculate time spent on everything that was specified with the regex. In other words, a command such as `gawk -f tst.awk file REGEX`. Does awk allow this kind of argument input?

Comment: What do you mean by "tasks containing multiple words"? Can task names contain spaces? If so how can you tell when a task name ends andthe next field begins? Are the fields actually tab-separated or separated by some other character? Yes you can use an RE. Once You answer the questions I'm sure you'll get some answers for that, in the meantime I added something to my answer to show you how it'd be done in general.

Comment: @mart: No problem! Don't forget to mark this answer as solved. Cheers!

Comment: @Ed: yes, that's what I meant -- task names have spaces. And they're separated by tabs. @steve: thank you (again :)! this works very well. I modified the `print` statement a little -- now it shows the result in hours, not seconds. Perfect for me.